# Map json Array in static method (Angular2+TS)

Tags: arrays, json, angular, typescript, mapping

Problem to get the syntax right to map my incoming data in a static method. My json Array looks like this:

```
[
    {
        "documents": [
            {
                "title": "+1 (film)",
                "is-saved": false,
                "abstract": "some text",
                "id": "_1__film_",
                "url": "some url"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Each item in that array is a `Result`.

As an example to refer to Mapping one Result I know how to do:

```
static resultFromJSON(json): Result {
    let documents: SearchQueryDocument[] =
        json.documents.map(doc => new SearchQueryDocument(doc.title, doc.issaved, doc.abstract, doc.id, doc.url))
        return new Result(documents)
}
```

But I need to map the whole array, so how do I do that?

```
static resultsFromJSON(json): Result[] {
    let results: Result =
    json.map ... // what here? 
}
```

Mapping one result I can use `json.documents.map...` but mapping the whole array it has no "name" to use...

Maybe a stupid question from a newbie, but any help is appreciated!

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. How can the same `json` end up as `Result` and `Result[]`?

Comment: I just put the mapping of one result as an example to refer to. I need to map the array :) I updated my question, so hopefully it's more clear!

Comment: Are you trying to create an array of arrays or a flat array with all of the SearchQueryDocuments?

Comment: I'm not sure of what you mean, newbie here. When I try to access the data I get an self implicit error, so I need to create a "new" results array, thus the static method. So I just need it as an array like the json object is to be able to use it.

Comment: Just want exactly the same as mapping ONE result, but for the whole array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution that worked for me was just a slight change to the above static method by Nitzan Tomer.

This worked:

```
static resultsFromJSON(json): Result[] {
    return json.map(obj => 
        new Result(obj.documents.map(doc => 
            new SearchQueryDocument(doc.title, doc.issaved, doc.abstract, doc.id, doc.url)
        ))
    )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly then your json corresponds to the following interfaces:

```
interface IDocument {
    title: string;
    "is-saved": boolean;
    "abstract": string;
    id: string;
    url: string;
}

interface IResult {
    documents: Document[];
}
```

And then you have an array of `Result`.
To map that json you can do:

```
static resultsFromJSON(json): Result[] {
    return json.map(obj => {
        new Result(obj.documents.map(doc => {
            return new SearchQueryDocument(doc.title, doc.issaved, doc.abstract, doc.id, doc.url);
        }));
    });
}
```

Comment: Now that looks like something I need, thanks! Almost there, `Result` now is correct, `SearchQueryDocument` is now undefined though when I try to display data in browser.

Comment: You'll need to supply more info/code to get more help, even what I did mange to answer was based on some guesses.

Comment: Just made a slight change and got it to work! Thanks for your help!